# How to animate a plane track

Tags: masking

I did some motion tracking and added a plane track, and the camera changes angles somewhat.  When it changes, the plane track slides off a little bit.  Since I can't fix the trackers very well, is it possible to animate the plane track so when the angle changes it will still be in place?  Thanks!

First frame:
[image]

Last frame:
[image]

Comment: You can manually place the trackers in place where they drift. Just select the tracker, press **G** to move it and place it where is should be.

Comment: Yes, it's just time consuming to do that for every frame, and I don't believe that is the main problem, I think I may have some sort of distortion or something, because the tracks seem to be staying in the right place.

Comment: can you illustrate your issue?

Comment: Sure, but it will take a little bit.  I'll upload some pictures in a while.

Comment: @cegaton Okay, I uploaded some images if you're interested.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not tracking the corners of the frame?

Comment: @cegaton They were sliding out of place too much.  I was kind of suprised how much they wanted to move inwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27557/discussion-between-cegaton-and-anson-savage).

Comment: The points you are tracking are too close together. Add points at either end of the bench so blender has a way to calculate the distortion.